# How to implement an adjacency matrix in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for the best possible way to implement the following problem in mysql .. i  am working on *phpmyadmin* .  Like 1 have 2 columns
"id" and "ingredients" in my table .. let say the table is ..

```
id        ingredient
201        Garlic
201        Ginger
202        tomato
203        Garlic
203        potato
203        Ginger....so on
```

I want to create the adjacency matrix with ingredient as column header and row header ..
like **ginger and garlic** both have a relation in **id 201 and id 203**
where as **garlic and potato** in **id 203** so according to this we will form adjacency matrix
and so on with all other ingredients

```
              Garlic   Ginger    Tomato        potato
  Garlic      0          2           0            1
  Ginger      2          0           0            1
  Tomato      0          0           0            0
  Potato      1          1           0            0....so on
```

and I also wanna store this in database like ingredient-ingredient relation

```
  ingredient     ingredient    frequency
   Garlic            Garlic        0
   Garlic            Ginger        2
   Garlic            Tomato        0
   Garlic            Potato        1
   Ginger            Garlic        2    .... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you got a table with the ingredient-ingredient frequencies, you can pivot on that.

> ```
> --
> -- Setup test data
> --
> create table ingredients (
>  id int not null, 
>  ingredient varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into ingredients (id, ingredient) values
>   (201, 'Garlic') 
> , (201, 'Ginger') 
> , (202, 'Tomato') 
> , (203, 'Garlic') 
> , (203, 'Potato') 
> , (203, 'Ginger')
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- a table for ingredient combinations
> --
> create table ingredient_combinations (
>  id int auto_increment primary key, 
>  ingredient1 varchar(30) not null, 
>  ingredient2 varchar(30) not null, 
>  frequency int default 0 not null
> )
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- insert all unique ingredient combinations
> --
> insert into ingredient_combinations (ingredient1, ingredient2)
> select distinct i1.ingredient, i2.ingredient
> from (select distinct ingredient from ingredients) i1
> cross join (select distinct ingredient from ingredients) i2
> where i1.ingredient < i2.ingredient
> order by i1.ingredient, i2.ingredient
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- update the frequencies
> --
> update ingredient_combinations combo
> left join (
>   select 
>     i1.ingredient as ingredient1
>   , i2.ingredient as ingredient2
>   , count(*) as frequency
>   from ingredients as i1
>   join ingredients as i2 
>     on i1.id = i2.id 
>    and i1.ingredient < i2.ingredient
>   group by i1.ingredient, i2.ingredient
>   having count(*) > 0
> ) q on combo.ingredient1 = q.ingredient1
>   and combo.ingredient2 = q.ingredient2
> set combo.frequency = coalesce(q.frequency, 0);
> ```

> ```
> -- what do we have so far
> select * from ingredient_combinations order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | ingredient1 | ingredient2 | frequency
> -: | :---------- | :---------- | --------:
>  1 | Garlic      | Ginger      |         2
>  2 | Garlic      | Potato      |         1
>  3 | Garlic      | Tomato      |         0
>  4 | Ginger      | Potato      |         1
>  5 | Ginger      | Tomato      |         0
>  6 | Potato      | Tomato      |         0
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- pivot the combos
> --
> with CTE_COMBOS as
> (
>   select ingredient1, ingredient2, frequency
>   from ingredient_combinations
>   union
>   select ingredient2, ingredient1, frequency
>   from ingredient_combinations
> )
> select ingredient1
> , max(case when ingredient2 = 'Garlic' then frequency else 0 end) as Garlic
> , max(case when ingredient2 = 'Ginger' then frequency else 0 end) as Ginger
> , max(case when ingredient2 = 'Potato' then frequency else 0 end) as Potato
> , max(case when ingredient2 = 'Tomato' then frequency else 0 end) as Tomato
> from CTE_COMBOS
> group by ingredient1
> order by ingredient1
> ```
>
> ```
> ingredient1 | Garlic | Ginger | Potato | Tomato
> :---------- | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----:
> Garlic      |      0 |      2 |      1 |      0
> Ginger      |      2 |      0 |      1 |      0
> Potato      |      1 |      1 |      0 |      0
> Tomato      |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76394d68f3189306fa8cd5e6ea61b286)*